# How to crop part of the image between guide lines?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

I have few photoshop files with blue guide lines like on this picture below. I want to quickly save only one part of the picture that is between these guides, in the middle. What is best way to do this?

I usually need to use *rectangular marquee tool* and make selection by following on these lines, but it's hard to find edges and perfectly match them to the blue line. Is there better way to do this?

[image: example]

Comment: Do you have snapping enabled? The Crop tool snaps to guidelines just fine for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option that came to my mind is save it using the **Slice Tool**:

**1.** With the Slice Tool selected, click on the "Slices from Guides" button at the top.

**2.** File → Save for Web

**3.** Select the "Slice Select Tool" (or press <kbd>C</kbd>) and select the slice you want to save (if you want to save multiple slides, select the additional ones while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> down).

**4.** Select the quality of the image etc.

**5.** Save to your location of choice. Make sure to chose "Selected Slices" from the drop-down menu at the bottom of your saving window. (Just a note: it will create a folder with that one image, so just move it where needed and get rid of the folder after.)

Here's a [video / GIF](http://recordit.co/L75IKNrqe6) going through the process I've described above.

---

This way you don't have to worry about your section following the guides, because the tool will make sure to snap the slices to your guides.

Comment: Very simple way that I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @thosetinydreams thank you for sharing this method of accurately cropping images between guides in Photoshop.